# Hive 0.14 on Tez : one file per insert, even with hive.merge. activated

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

Every 15 minutes I need to insert datas to different tables stored as ORC and aggregates the values. Those INSERT use dynamic partitions.
Each INSERT create a new file in the partition, which is slow down my aggregation queries. I've search on the web, found some subjects about this case like [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096347/hive-create-multi-small-files-for-each-insert-in-hdfs)

So I've added on the hive-site.xml those settings :

```
hive.merge.mapfiles =true;
hive.merge.mapredfiles =true;
hive.merge.tezfiles = true
hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=256000000;
```

But even with those settings, each insert create a new file on each partitions and files are not merged.

Is someone have an idea on how I can solve this issue ?

My cluster is an Azure HDInsight cluster 3.2, with Hive 0.14, Tez 0.5.2.
My insert query is like this one :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE measures PARTITION(year, month, day)
SELECT  area,
    device,
    date,
    val,
    year,
    month,
    day
FROM stagingmeasures
DISTRIBUTE BY year, month, day;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a swap table for your target table(like below) so that all the small files will be merged into a single file. 
Drop the original table and rename the swap table to original table.

Do this once in a day.

```
CREATE TABLE swap_measures SELECT * FROM measures;
DROP TABLE measures;
ALTER TABLE swap_measures RENAME TO measures;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to stream directly into Hive using the ORC format, look at the link below to read more on the Hive Streaming API

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Streaming+Data+Ingest

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this link. I'll try it.