# How to do append insertion in sparksql?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a api endpoint written by sparksql with the following sample code. Every time api accept a request it will run sparkSession.sql(sql_to_hive) which would create a single file in HDFS. Is there any way to do insert by appending data to existing file in HDFS ? Thanks.

```
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sparkSession.sparkContext)
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(ziped_tuple_list, schema=schema)
    df.registerTempTable('TMP_TABLE')
    sql_to_hive = 'insert into log.%(table_name)s partition%(partition)s select %(title_str)s from TMP_TABLE'%{
        'table_name': table_name,
        'partition': partition_day,
        'title_str': title_str
    }
    sparkSession.sql(sql_to_hive)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible case to append data to the existing file.

But you can work around this case by using either of these ways

***Approach1***

**`Using Spark, write to intermediate temporary table and then insert overwrite to final table:`**

```
existing_df=spark.table("existing_hive_table") //get the current data from hive
current_df //new dataframe
union_df=existing_df.union(current_df) 
union_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("temp_table") //write the data to temp table
temp_df=spark.table("temp_table") //get data from temp table
temp_df.repartition(<number>).write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("existing_hive_table") //overwrite to final table
```

***Approach2:***

**`Hive(not spark)`** offers overwriting and select same table .i.e

```
insert overwrite table default.t1 partition(partiton_column) 
select * from default.t1; //overwrite and select from same t1 table
```

If you are following this way then there needs to be hive job triggered once your spark job finishes.

Hive will acquire lock while running overwrite/select the same table so if any job which is writing to table will wait.

**`In Addition:`** `Orc format` will offer [alter table concatenate](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionConcatenate) which will merge small ORC files to create a new larger file.

```
 alter table <db_name>.<orc_table_name> [partition_column="val"] concatenate;
```

We can also use `distributeby,sortby clauses` to control number of files, refer [this](http://I%20don't%20think%20this%20is%20possible%20case.%20%20But%20you%20can%20work%20around%20this%20case%20by%20using%20either%20of%20these%20ways%20%20***Approach1***%20%20**%60Using%20Spark,%20write%20to%20intermediate%20temporary%20table%20and%20then%20insert%20overwrite%20to%20final%20table:%60**%20%20%20%20%20%20existing_df=spark.table(%22existing_hive_table%22)%20//get%20the%20current%20data%20from%20hive%20%20%20%20%20current_df%20//new%20dataframe%20%20%20%20%20union_df=existing_df.union(current_df)%20%20%20%20%20%20union_df.write.mode(%22overwrite%22).saveAsTable(%22temp_table%22)%20//write%20the%20data%20to%20temp%20table%20%20%20%20%20temp_df=spark.table(%22temp_table%22)%20//get%20data%20from%20temp%20table%20%20%20%20%20temp_df.repartition(%3Cnumber%3E).write.mode(%22overwrite%22).saveAsTable(%22existing_hive_table%22)%20//overwrite%20to%20final%20table%20%20%20%20***Approach2:***%20%20**%60Hive(not%20spark)%60**%20offers%20overwriting%20and%20select%20same%20table%20.i.e%20%20%20%20%20%20insert%20overwrite%20table%20default.t1%20partition(partiton_column)%20%20%20%20%20%20select%20*%20from%20default.t1;%20//overwrite%20and%20select%20from%20same%20t1%20table%20%20If%20you%20are%20following%20this%20way%20then%20there%20needs%20to%20be%20hive%20job%20triggered%20once%20your%20spark%20job%20finishes.%20%20Hive%20will%20acquire%20lock%20while%20running%20overwrite/select%20the%20same%20table%20so%20if%20any%20job%20which%20is%20writing%20to%20table%20will%20wait.%20%20**%60In%20Addition:%60**%20%60Orc%20format%60%20will%20offer%20[alter%20table%20concatenate][1]%20which%20will%20merge%20small%20ORC%20files%20to%20create%20a%20new%20larger%20file.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alter%20table%20%3Cdb_name%3E.%3Corc_table_name%3E%20[partition_column=%22val%22]%20concatenate;%20%20%20%20In%20addition%20we%20can%20also%20use%20distributeby%20sortby%20to%20control%20number%20of%20files,%20refer%20this%20and%20[this][2]%20link%20for%20more%20details.%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionConcatenate%20%20%20[2]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096347/hive-create-multi-small-files-for-each-insert-in-hdfs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096347/hive-create-multi-small-files-for-each-insert-in-hdfs) link for more details.

Another ***Approach3*** is by using [hadoop fs -getMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103872/merging-small-files-in-hadoop) to merge all small files into one (this method `works` for `text files` and `i haven't tried` for **orc,avro** ..etc formats).

Answer (score 0):

When you write the resulted dataframe:

result_df = sparkSession.sql(sql_to_hive)

set it’s mode to append:

result_df.write.mode(**SaveMode.Append**).